# css custom border style (triangles or arrows)

Tags: css

How to create the below abstract pattern for CSS border-style.

```
 /\   /\  
/  \ /  \
---------
         |\
         | \
         | /
         |/
         |\
         | \
         | /
         |/
         |\
         | \
         | /
         |/
```

PS: I can't add images

Comment: Have you tried researching this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain multiple 'triangles' around a single element as you have indicated with your example, I think your only option is the `border-image` property

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eLMGv/)**

**CSS**

```
div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    margin:25px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 13px 14px 14px 12px;
    -moz-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 13 14 14 12 round;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 13 14 14 12 round;
    -o-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 13 14 14 12 round;
    border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 13 14 14 12 round;
}
```

**NB. This property requires you to have a 'base' image to work from.**

[**W3C**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images)

[**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/border-image)

[**Border Image Generator**](http://border-image.com/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to fit the "PS" requirement.

Comment: @dystroy I assume the PS comment refers to him not being able to post images on SO due to lack of reputation. In any case, it's a CSS property not an inline HTML image.

Comment: Might be... OP not following what happens to his question doesn't help. In any case +1

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's no predefined CSS rule for this, but you can still do this.

Here, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mMry/)

```
    <div class="wrapper">
<div class="arrow_box">
    <div>
<div class="arrow_box_2">
    <div>
<div class="arrow_box_3">
    <div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
}
.arrow_box {
    position: absolute;
    background: #88b7d5;
    border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
    height:100px;
    width:40px;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 26px;
    margin-left: -26px;
}

.arrow_box_2 {
    position: absolute;
    background: #88b7d5;
    border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
    border-left:none;
    height:100px;
    width:50px;
    top:-4px;
    left:30px;

}
.arrow_box_2:after, .arrow_box_2:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box_2:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.arrow_box_2:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 26px;
    margin-left: -26px;
}
.arrow_box_3 {
    position: absolute;
    background: #88b7d5;
    border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
    border-left:none;
    height:100px;
    width:45px;
    top:-4px;
    left:45px;

}
.arrow_box_3:after, .arrow_box_3:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box_3:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.arrow_box_3:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 26px;
    margin-left: -26px;
}
```

Your question has been downvoted because you don't seem to have researched. Remember, GIYF.

Here's a tool to help you understand how it is done - http://cssarrowplease.com

Comment: This solution relies on multiple divs which is not what the OP wanted. He wants **multiple** triangles around a larger div.

Comment: Well, he didn't specifically say he wants it on a single div.

Comment: No. The text block he has provided indicates he'd need a block having triangles outside, using CSS. Besides, there can be a workaround to have content within the wrapper, if he wants. But he hasn't specified it.

Comment: One of the workarounds to add content in the container I can think of right now - http://jsfiddle.net/2mMry/1/ There obviously can be others, but I think it's better to focus on other productive things rather than convincing you.